# Insertar palabra y no value en mi base de datos

Tags: javascript, select

Tengo un formulario de actualizar, donde esta un select y puedes escoger el area si se quiere editar, al elegir cualquiera, en mi base de datos actualiza al value de la opcion.

Estos datos se llenan a travez de js, no son estaticos dentro del html.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En una tabla html donde se muestran los datos, al actualizar el area, este me muestra el value 2, que corresponde a Auxitrol. Y donde necesito que se muestre la palabra.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy llenando los datos en la tabla por medio de una function en js.
Y aqui es donde digo que mostrara el area.

```
var CellArea = document.createElement('td');
CellArea.innerHTML = activos[i].name_area;
```

Comment: Subi la estructura de las tablas y la consulta que arman ese dato, en la consulta podes meter un join relacionado con la tabla localidad y seguis guardando el id pero en al tabla mostras el nombre, o sea subi como se arma esto: activos[i]

Comment: Podrías mostrar la función donde llenas la tabla, creo que tu problema radica en que deberias de guardar el .text() en lugar del .val() de tu select option (outAreaEdit).

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener el texto de una opción en concreto de un elemento <select> puedes usar el siguiente código :

```js
var valor = "2";
var options_select = document.getElementById("outAreaEdit").options;
var array = [...options_select];

var encontrado = array.find(function(elemento) {
  return elemento.value == valor;
});

console.log("El texto es " + encontrado.text);

var CellArea = document.createElement('td');
CellArea.innerHTML = encontrado.text;
```

```html
<select class='form-control' id='outAreaEdit'>

  <option value='4'>Norwich</option>
  <option value='3'>Todas las Areas</option>
  <option value='2'>Auxitrol</option>
  <option value='1'>Weston</option>

</select>
```